# How to use a full width image as border between content and footer

Tags: php, css, wordpress, customization

at the moment I have a green border line between content and footer. configured through theme settings. I want to have an image instead. Should look like grass growing on the border line. Check screenshots! How do I do that? CSS maybe? Using Wordpress Jupiter theme.

Thanks

**With green line**
[image: green line]

---

**With grass as border**

[image: with grass as border]

Comment: `border-image` *can* be of service. or `background-position: bottom center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background-image` property with `background-repeat`.

Have a look at the snippet below (*`wait for the image to load`*):

```css
.divider {
  height: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/3/');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae obcaecati assumenda provident molestias fugit aperiam, at cumque voluptate tenetur, ab ratione magnam ipsa in aspernatur ipsum, error modi iste harum.</div>

<div class="divider"></div>

<div class="bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet quidem eius deserunt aut suscipit blanditiis omnis a alias dolorem consequatur mollitia molestias architecto consequuntur asperiores minima sapiente laudantium, quisquam saepe.</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Saurav, I have implemented and it's working beautifully on some pages but not on all. I have a global background image. Even though the divider image has transparent background it sometimes makes it white and sometimes not. 

See first link where it works and second where it doesn't.

https://test.storl.de/veranstaltungen/
https://test.storl.de/kontakt/

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Patrick I need to see some example, I can't solve it without having a look at it.

Comment: When you check the two links I posted you can see that under  [link] (test.storl.de/veranstaltungen) the grass image has a transparent background and merges seemingness with the background of the page. Under [link] (test.storl.de/kontakt) the background of the grass image is white and it creates a border, it should be like the first example. -no white

Can you help?

Comment: @Patrick I got the issue, You should use the `<div class="divider"></div>` inside the `<div id="theme-page" class="master-holder clearfix"></div>`. Currently you've used it outside of it. Hope you got my point, let me know if you didn't get it.

Comment: I basically understand what you are saying but cannot find the right place to put the <div class="divider"></div>

Comment: If you have a look at the footer.php where I placed it, maybe you can tell me where the correct position is. Because if I place it further down, then it @Saurav appears under the borderline and not on top. Sorry, I'm not so good at this. But thanks again for your help.

[link](https://
cl.ly/34181W0D3w2A)

Comment: @Patrick Just add `background: url(https://test.storl.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/paper_fibers_@2X.png);` to your `body`. This will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried that: 
#theme-page {
    background-image: url("https://test.storl.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/paper_fibers_@2X.png") ;
}

It doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @Patrick You are doing it wrong. You should write the exact CSS like - `body { background: url(https://test.storl.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/paper_f‌​ibers_@2X.png); }` in your CSS file and then test it.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it didn't work. "body" didn't have any effect. The paper_fiber background image doesn't show. Tried ' and " within the brackets as well. No luck

Comment: @Patrick There is some problem in the `image url` you are using, on opening the background image link its showing `404 not found`. Please use the relative path as you've used in other pages.

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Thank you very much for your expertise and your patience. Everything is working.

Comment: @Patrick Its my pleasure! Its good, that at the end you got your solution. Always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

ah im late, but though it might be useful

```css
footer, header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.divider{
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://wiltdasney.applicationcraft.com/service/Resources/fbb6ab3d-4f74-49c9-84ab-0395c41d42d8.png) center bottom repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>

content

</header>

<div class="divider"></div>

<footer>
footer

</footer>
```